# Adjusting the width of a label

Tags: c#, loops, random, listbox

I am creating a fairly complicated system that seems quite simple... as far as I can tell most everything is working correctly at this moment. The program is when a person clicks a button this button updates 2 separate listbox one tracks the total rolls the other displays the total amounts of frequency afterwards adjusting labels as a scaling measurement.

The problem I am having is right at the end where I am trying to adjust the width of the label this is what I have. It is highlighting the word "Items" for each label and says that Non-Invokable member 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.Items' Cannot be used like a method
L2 is a label. Additionally I have added in the information for one of my loops below the line I am having trouble with this loop is created to determine how many lines are in the listbox of rolls and I have no trouble with this just thought id add it for additional information I dont think I need to add the rest of the code but I can if needed.

```
L2.Width = int.Parse(lstfrequency.Items[0].ToString());


TL = 0;
for (I = 0; I <= 10; I++)
{ 
TL += int.Parse(lstfrequency.Items[I].ToString());
}
lstfrequency.Items.Add(TL);
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking. Please try and re-format, re-word or something.

Comment: Bradley is right I am really confused also, but just a shot in the dark, perhaps you should use square brackets: `L2.Width = int.Parse(lstfrequency.Items[0].ToString());` when getting your item.  You do that for the `TL` line but not for the `L2` line

Comment: @chancea I think your spot on- .Item[#] accesses the index whereas Item(#) tries to call that method passing it a number, and that method doesn't exist.

Comment: @chancea I agree that looks like his problem. I guess I should have just read the code and ignored the question (sad as that is).

Comment: Basically trying to figure out why is it telling me that "Items" does not work in that first line of code that I posted and how to get it to accept it.

Comment: @user3598883, You have your answer. You are accessing it like a method, you wanted an array access (using square brackets). Did that not fix it?

Comment: Ahh yes using brackets does work fine. I also love how people give you a - comment on a question you are trying to get fixed for something doesnt really make sense oh well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
L2.Width = int.Parse(lstfrequency.Items(0).ToString());
```

You are calling `.Items(0)` which the compiler interprets as a method call passing in an integer value of 0.  However there is no method `Items(int value)` for a `ListBox` you need to be index accessing the item with square brackets as such:

```
L2.Width = int.Parse(lstfrequency.Items[0].ToString());
```

This will retrieve the item located at position 0 from the item list

Comment: This works great so now that it doesnt say there is an error, however it still does not actually extend the width of my labels any ideas as to why?

Comment: @user3598883 my initial guess would be that the [Label.AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx) property was left to true.  If you want to adjust the labels width manually you would need that property to be false.

Comment: Hmm okay so I added the auto size to false... and now the top line adjusts (for #2) but the rest of the numbers wont adjust infact they actually just disappear completely

Comment: @user3598883 I am unsure of what you mean by _the rest of the numbers_  what numbers exactly?  Are they characters inside `L2`?